# trouble trying to use a struct variable

Tags: c, struct

I’m learning C programming and I’m trying to make a simple program to store points in the XY plane.

At first I did it like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct point { float x, y; } PNT;
typedef struct plane
{
    int n_points;
    PNT pt[50];

} plane;
void points_input(plane planexy);
void points_distance(plane planexy);
int main()
{
    plane planexy;
    printf("How many points do you want to enter? : ");
    scanf("%d", &planexy.n_points);
    points_input(planexy);
    points_distance(planexy);
}
void points_input(plane planexy)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < planexy.n_points; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a coordinate for x%d ", i);
        scanf("%f", &planexy.pt[i].x);
        printf("\nEnter a coordinate for y%d ", i);
        scanf("%f", &planexy.pt[i].y);
        system("cls");
    }
}
void points_distance(plane planexy)
{
    int i;
    printf("Select first point :\n");

    for (i = 0; i < planexy.n_points; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d.(%.1f ,%.1f)", i, planexy.pt[i].x, planexy.pt[i].y);
    }
}
```

And it doesn’t work, when I try to access one of the variables of a point it always returns a 0.

After messing with the variable name “planexy” and using it as a vector of size 1, and then using all mentions of it as planexy[0], it suddenly started to work :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct point { float x, y; } PNT;
typedef struct plane
{
    int n_points;
    PNT pt[50];

} plane;
void points_input(plane planexy[]);
void points_distance(plane planexy[]);
int main()
{
    plane planexy[1];
    printf("How many points do you want to enter? : ");
    scanf("%d", &planexy[0].n_points);
    points_input(planexy);
    points_distance(planexy);
}
void points_input(plane planexy[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < planexy[0].n_points; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a coordinate for x%d ", i);
        scanf("%f", &planexy[0].pt[i].x);
        printf("\nEnter a coordinate for y%d ", i);
        scanf("%f", &planexy[0].pt[i].y);
        system("cls");
    }
}
void points_distance(plane planexy[])
{
    int i;
    printf("Select first point :\n");

    for (i = 0; i < planexy[0].n_points; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %d.(%.1f ,%.1f)", i, planexy[0].pt[i].x, planexy[0].pt[i].y);
    }
}
```

Now, this code works, but I don’t know why I had to put it this way for it to function, and it doesn't seem like it's good code.

I get that if I want to use multiple planes "XY" I should store the variable as a vector, but I just want to use one, I don't understand why it works when I use a vector of size 1 but it doesn't when I just want to use one variable to store a single plane.

What's wrong with the first approach?

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Your first code cannot possibly return anything since it does not even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited your question to English so other people can understand it in SO.
I hope you accept it as I'll answer in English.

You're passing a **copy** of the object `planexy` in the function `points_input()` so the actual `planexy` that's defined in `main()` doesn't change. Instead, you should pass a pointer that *points to it* then modify the object pointed by that pointer.

The modified code:

**Forward declartion**

```
void points_input(plane* planexy); // ingreso_puntos function
```

**Code**

```
void points_input(plane* planexy)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < planexy->n_points; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter a coordinate for x%d ", i);
        scanf("%f", &planexy->pt[i].x);
        printf("\nEnter a coordinate for y%d ", i);
        scanf("%f", &planexy->pt[i].y);
        system("cls");
    }
}
```

When using pointers, you use `->` instead of the dot `.` which is only for objects.

Why did it work with an array as your second code?

> Simply, **arrays**/**vectors** are actual pointers by themselves.

**Proof:**
 `scanf("%f", &planexy[0].pt[i].x);` is the same as `scanf("%f", &planexy->pt[i].x);`.

In **`main()`**. You should pass the *address* of the `planexy` which creates the pointer.

```
points_input(&planexy);
```

**Tip:** When you want to **modify** an object through a function, you pass a pointer to it exactly as you do with `scanf`. Otherwise, when you want to just **read** an object, you pass it normally.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you get from the compiler when you compile this tell you what is wrong:

```
program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:23:20: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘ingreso_puntos’
     ingreso_puntos(planexy);
                    ^
program.c:15:6: note: expected ‘plane * {aka struct plane *}’ but argument is of type ‘plane {aka struct plane}’
 void ingreso_puntos(plane planexy[]);
      ^
```

You've declared your functions as taking a pointer to a plane (`plane *`), but you're calling them with a plane.  Use the `&` operator to get the address of `planexy` to pass to the function.

```
program.c: In function ‘ingreso_puntos’:
program.c:31:28: error: request for member ‘n_puntos’ in something not a structure or union
     for (i = 0; i < planexy.n_puntos; i++)
                            ^
```

Here in the function, `planexy` is a pointer to a plane, so you need `->` instead of `.` to access fields from it.